# Why strcpy(buffer +i, buffer + i +1) doesn't work in the same way as using a temporay array?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c-strings, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[200] = "This is a string";
    char buffer1[200];
    strcpy(buffer1, buffer);
    char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) {
        if (strchr(vowels, buffer[i]) != NULL) {
            char tmp[1000];
            strcpy(tmp, buffer + i + 1);
            strcpy(buffer + i, tmp);
            
            strcpy(buffer1 + i, buffer1 + i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("buffer=%s\n", buffer); // prints "Ths is a string", which is OK
    printf("buffer1=%s\n", buffer1); // prints "Ths is asstring", which is not OK.
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to remove a character from a string.
In the code below I used to 2 ways to achieve this, with the variables *buffer* and *buffer1*. But, one of them, **buffer1**, prints a weird result.

What makes buffer and buffer1 contain different values?

Comment: `strcpy()` doesn't allow the source and destination to overlap. Use `memmove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `strcpy` for overlapping arrays invokes undefined behavior. In such a case you should use `memmove`.

From the C Standard (7.23.2.3 The strcpy function)

> 2. ... If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the
>    behavior is undefined.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char buffer[200] = "This is a string";
    char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";

    size_t n = strlen( buffer );

    size_t pos = strcspn( buffer, vowels );

    memmove( buffer + pos, buffer + pos + 1, n - pos );

    puts( buffer );
}
```

The program output is

```
Ths is a string
```

Answer (score 2):

**Do not overlap**

`char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);` has `restrict` which informs the caller to not provide pointers to overlapping data.

OP's code used overlapping data and so has *undefined behavior* (UB).
Don't do that.

---

Could use `memmove()` which handles overlapping data.

```
size_t sz = strlen(buffer1 + i + 1) + 1;
memmove(buffer1 + i, buffer1 + i + 1, sz);
```

Comment: Where did you get that declaration for *strcpy* from? I looked in the manual for strcpy on my system, but the word _restrict_ doesn't appear.

Comment: C17 draft spec.  `restrict` has been around since C11, maybe C99.  Between man pages and the C spec, best to consult the  C spec per the version you are using.

Comment: Do you have a link to it, or a copy?